# Backup and sync solution for online and offline

Tags: windows-7, backup

I am looking for an software that provides online and offline backup for my files. It would be nice, if there is a free version of it.

I want to sync mydocs between my home-pc and my laptop both using Windows 7.
I want to backup my music and films locally on my WD MyBook world edition.
It should only track changes.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the amount of data, music and video takes up a lot of space. For those I suggest setting up (or renting) a storage server and use [rsync](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=rsync+backup+howto+windows).

For your documents I suggest [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)

Dropbox allows you to sync your files online and across your computers automatically.

```
* 2GB of online storage for free, with up to 100GB available to paying customers.
* Sync files of any size or type.
* Sync Windows, Mac and Linux computers.
* Automatically syncs when new files or changes are detected.
* Work on files in your Dropbox even if you're offline. Your changes sync once your computer has an Internet connection again.
* Dropbox transfers will correctly resume where they left off if the connection drops.
* Efficient sync - only the pieces of a file that changed (not the whole file) are synced. This saves you time.
* Doesn't hog your Internet connection. You can manually set bandwidth limits.
```

Online Backup

Dropbox backs up your files online without you having to think about it.

```
* Automatic backup of your files.
* Undelete files and folders.
* Restore previous versions of your files.
* 30 days of undo history, with unlimited undo available as a paid option.
```

Comment: is there maybe a oneapp solution?

Comment: I really like Dropbox. You start with 2GB but can get upto 8GB if you refer others to use it. I would pay for it for that amount of money since they are super fast to synch. I've used others (Mozy and Backblaze) and found them too slow to upload and retrieve backups.

Comment: I'd put my vote in for dropbox. I'm a paying member with their 50gb plan. Its some of the best money you can spend on storage/syncing. I've never had a problem with the sync and no you can link files directly to another person to share data.

Answer (score 0):

[SpiderOak](https://spideroak.com/) is a better option than Dropbox because it includes client-side encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Wuala](http://wua.la). It also has client-side encryption. Compared to dropbox you can choose the installation folder and the cache folder. Also you can limit the bandwith used for upload and download....and many more features.

I don't know of a free onlinestorage greater than 5 GB. So you'll end up paying some fees.

You could go for a complete local solution though. [PureSync](http://www.jumpingbytes.com/puresync.html) is free for private usage. Just synch via your MyBook to both computers (assuming it is a network attached device not USB and you have enough disk space).